# Align vertically subfigures containing dirtrees

Tags: vertical-alignment, subfloats, subcaption, dirtree

I want to align two [`dirtrees`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/dirtree) to the **top** and their respective [`subcaptions`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) to the **bottom**. What's more, height of the both [`frameboxes`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes#framebox) should be equal (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvpFZ.png) below). How can I achieve that?

Here is the image presenting my problem:
[image: Trees in subfigures]

Here is the respective code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{dirtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \framebox[\textwidth]{%
            \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
                \footnotesize
                \dirtree{%
                .1 /.
                .2 \vdots.
                .2 tmp.
                .3 \vdots.
                .3 test.
                .4 file0.
                .4 file1.
                .4 file1\_symlink -> file1.
                .4 dir3\_symlink -> dir3.
                .4 file8\_hardlink.
                .4 dir1.
                .5 fi.
                .5 file2.
                .5 file3.
                .5 subdir1.
                .6 file4.
                .6 file5.
                .5 subdir2.
                .6 file6.
                .6 file7.
                .4 dir2.
                .5 fifo1.
                .5 fifo2.
                .4 dir3.
                .5 file8.
                .5 file9.
                }
                \caption{Tree 1}
                \label{subfig:tree1}
            \end{minipage}
        }
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \framebox[\textwidth]{%
            \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
                \footnotesize
                \dirtree{%
                .1 /.
                .2 \vdots.
                .2 tmp.
                .3 \vdots.
                .3 test.
                .4 dir1.
                .5 f3.
                .5 f4.
                .5 subdir1.
                .5 subdir2.
                .6 f5.
                .4 dir2.
                .4 dir3.
                .4 f1.
                .4 f2.
                .4 f2\_symlink -> f2.
                .4 f4\_hardlink.
                .4 fifo1.
                .4 fifo2.
                }
                \caption{Tree 2}
                \label{subfig:tree2}
            \end{minipage}
        }
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Comparison}
    \label{fig:trees-comparison}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `tcolorbox` provides a series of command that help with this and it will also simplify your code.  The most relevant feature is that it can construct boxes with an upper and lower part, distribute space between them and give a series of boxes the same height.

```
\NewTotalTColorBox{\mybox}{m +m}{equal height group=#1, size=fbox,
sharp corners, colback=white, width=\textwidth, space to upper,
lower separated=false, fontupper=\footnotesize, nobeforeafter}{#2}
```

sets up a box command that takes two arguments, the first the name of the series of boxes that should have the same height, the second the content of the box.

The `size=fbox, sharp corners, colback=white` make this box much like an ordinary `\fbox` with no fancy colouring of the backgroup.

`space to upper` ensure that the part of the contents above `\tcblower` is top aligned and that the remainder is aligned to the bottom.

`lower separated=false` turns off `tcolorbox`'s standard printing of a dividing line.

`fontupper` sets the font to use in the upper part, instead of having to write it each time.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{dirtree}
\usepackage[xparse]{tcolorbox}

\NewTotalTColorBox{\mybox}{m +m}{equal height group=#1, size=fbox,
sharp corners, colback=white, width=\textwidth, space to upper,
lower separated=false, fontupper=\footnotesize, nobeforeafter}{#2}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \mybox{dirs}{%
    \dirtree{%
    .1 /.
    .2 \vdots.
    .2 tmp.
    .3 \vdots.
    .3 test.
    .4 file0.
    .4 file1.
    .4 file1\_symlink -> file1.
    .4 dir3\_symlink -> dir3.
    .4 file8\_hardlink.
    .4 dir1.
    .5 fi.
    .5 file2.
    .5 file3.
    .5 subdir1.
    .6 file4.
    .6 file5.
    .5 subdir2.
    .6 file6.
    .6 file7.
    .4 dir2.
    .5 fifo1.
    .5 fifo2.
    .4 dir3.
    .5 file8.
    .5 file9.
    }
    \tcblower
    \caption{Tree 1}
    \label{subfig:tree1}
    }
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \mybox{dirs}{%
    \dirtree{%
    .1 /.
    .2 \vdots.
    .2 tmp.
    .3 \vdots.
    .3 test.
    .4 dir1.
    .5 f3.
    .5 f4.
    .5 subdir1.
    .5 subdir2.
    .6 f5.
    .4 dir2.
    .4 dir3.
    .4 f1.
    .4 f2.
    .4 f2\_symlink -> f2.
    .4 f4\_hardlink.
    .4 fifo1.
    .4 fifo2.
    }
    \tcblower
    \caption{Tree 2}
    \label{subfig:tree2}
    }
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Comparison}
  \label{fig:trees-comparison}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```